# How to get index of the lpop'ed or rpop'ed item of Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am working on real-time analytics using `Redis` as in-memory database. In my analytics, I keep on doing `rpop` on growing `Redis-list` to perform analytics on every `rpop'ed` items. To perform clean-up of `Redis-list` and not to allow growing up enormously, I should extract and make a back-up of `Redis-list` at `23:59:59` of every day. 
 
If I blindly do a clean-up on Redis-list exactly at `23:59:59`, there are possiblity that few elements which are not `lpop'ed` or `rpop'ed` may get cleaned-up. Index is the best option to clean-up the growing list while it's being analyzed. 
 
Is there any `Redis-commands` to get the index of `lpop'ed` or `rpop'ed` item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand, when you pop list, you want value **and** index of value.
In case of lpop, index is alway 0.
In case of rpop, only way is use llen.

To run llen and rpop in *one time*, you need use transaction like :

```
MULTI
LLEN my-queue
RPOP myqueue
EXEC
```

Regards,